# What faulty logic is causing this push_back(...) function of my linked list to fail?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

For some reason

```
template <typename T> void SinglyLinkedList<T>::push_back ( T v )
{
   node * newNode = new node;
   newNode->val = v;
   newNode->next = NULL;
   if (_root != NULL)
   {
     node * thisNode = _root; 
     while (thisNode->next != NULL) thisNode = thisNode->next;
     thisNode->next = newNode;
   }
   else
   {
     _root = newNode;
   }    
}
```

has incorrect logic and I need some help figuring out what it is. When I tested

```
int myArray [] = { 1, 69, -23942, 69, 56, 67 };
SinglyLinkedList<int> myList(myArray, sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(int));
myList.push_back(33);
myList.print();
```

it printed

```
1->69->-23942->69->56->33->33->33->33->33-> ...
```

until the program crashed.

I'll explain my logic so that you can pinpoint where I'm wrong:

```
node * newNode = new node;
newNode->val = v;
newNode->next = NULL;
```

creates a new `node` object on the heap and initializes its value to `v` and its pointer to the next node as `NULL`. This is the node that will be added on to the end of the list. The end of the list will either be

(1) a final element whose `next` is `NULL`

or

(2) non-existent, meaning there are no elements, hence no final element

For micro-optimability, because I expect case (1) to occur more often I put it inside the `if` clause that is to follow and put case (2) inside the `else` clause.

Case (2) occurs if and only if the `_root` `node` is `NULL`, meaning the list is empty, and the handling of it is simply to make that `_root` be `newNode`:

```
   else
   {
     _root = newNode;
   }
```

Case (1) requires finding the final node and setting its `next` to `newNode`, which should be accomplished very simply with the 3 lines

```
     node * thisNode = _root; 
     while (thisNode->next != NULL) thisNode = thisNode->next;
     thisNode->next = newNode;
```

What is the flaw in that logic?

Comment: What is the definition of your node?

Comment: @Steephen it's simple `struct node { T val; node * next; }` defined inside the class

Comment: Didn't you define head and tail variables for your Linked List?

Comment: @Steephen No, I don't keep track of the tail

Comment: Can you show your constructor that takes an array, it is possible the error is there.

Comment: Here is the full code: http://codepad.org/OVQNGCmk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your constructor. This line:

```
delete lastNode;
```

is deleting memory that your are still using (the node that `lastnode` points to has just been put in your list).

Remove that line.

Edit: further explanation. Once the memory that `lastnode` points to is freed, the runtime can then use that memory again for another call to `new`. In your your case you have probably ended up with `newNode` and `thisNode` pointing to the same location, causing the node to point to itself.

Comment: Ah, you're right that I don't need to delete that node. I'm so used to the rule "whenever you use `new`, always make sure to have a corresponding `delete`" that I used it in an instance when I still needed the object and it would automatically be deleted when out of use (at the end of the program)

Answer (score 0):

when you delete last node, the node which its next is null deleted and the previous one next pointer is not null so when you parse the linked list you directed to unknown memory places!!!